Is it possible to append headers to the ones that were already configured?
In my karate config file, I have the following line:
karate.configure('headers', {X-Turn-Off-Forwarding: on});

I need this header to always persist when I make requests.
Now within my individual feature files, I also sometimes have
* configure headers = { Authorization: '#(bearerToken)' }

Unfortunately, this overwrites the header I had previously configured. Now I could remedy this by using header instead of configure headers everywhere in my feature files, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.
Is there a way to append to headers already configured rather than having to overwrite them?
